# Unit and integration testing an Android app that involves multiple users interacting with app in real-time

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I've been gleaming the Android documentation out there on testing but I was just wondering how one would go about testing features in Android involving the interaction of multiple users such as in a chat application or a posting forum.

I would assume for unit testing a fair bit of mocking and stubbing would be used, and I've been thinking for integration testing I would have to launch multiple emulators to simulate how actual users would be using the application. The multiple emulators method seems like a plausible solution but fairly slow and somewhat of a hindrance to the development lifecycle. Also does anyone have experience testing applications with websockets where data comes in real-time?

Perhaps my mindset towards testing an application like this may be wrong, but if anyone could provide some advice or guidance on how to go about doing this that'd be great.

Comment: You should rely on your database to sort out the concurrency problems.  Any testing at the unit level on such things would be tantamount to testing the database, and I assume that you picked one that is already robust.  You can, of course, perform stress-testing, but that's not unit testing, and I suspect that you don't need it... yet.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Do you mean dynamically loading mock data from the database that would simulate how multiple users would interact? How could you do something like that with websockets?

Comment: Mocks will not test user concurrency in a realistic manner.  For that, you need a real database. Websockets is just real-time database access.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Correct me if I'm wrong, would I use a SQLite database in an emulator and load data from there to simulate a user or multiple users?

Comment: You can do that, but unless you're also using SQLite for your actual live application, your *concurrency and stress test* results won't be valid.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, so would it be practical to use a database that I have in a server somewhere and use data from there? What other possible solutions to this might there be?

Comment: Did I mention that it's probably premature to do stress testing at this point?  How many simultaneous users do you expect to have next week?  In a year?  Just follow good practices and let the database do the work.